Missing flashing on roofline siding?
I was looking at my roof and I'm wondering if I'm missing flashing.
My roof is at two different heights. I am replacing a cedar siding shingle in the vertical space between rooflines. Looking between cracks in the lower row of shingles, I can see wood along the lower roofline. I'm no pro (1st time homeowner, new-to-me 1960's home), but I would have expected to see some metal flashing or something where the roofline meets the vertical wall so water that is running down the roof doesn't spill off into my house.
Should I be concerned? (What should I expect to find where the roofline meets the vertical wall?)



Regardless of the flashing issue, the siding wood should not contact the roof shingles as they do. The ends will invariably be soaked with every rain, water will be wicked up into the grain, rot will ensue, and any paint applied there will quickly fail. As I recall, a 2-inch gap is recommended for red cedar shingles.

Your photos do not establish the lack of step flashing at the roof-wall intersection.

This should've been a comment requesting more photos or investigation.

A better strategy might be to look for the flashing in the roof. It may be buried under several layers on the wall, but it will need to be under each row of shingles. Here's a reference image. Gently lift some tabs and see what you see.

source

There seems to be a little edge of flashing peeking out from under the top roof shingle in the first photo.
